# how to use .to_csv to write data to tsv file without combining everything in one column?

Tags: python, pandas

I try to copy some data from a .xlsx file to a .tsv file, but when I use to_csv it combined everything in one column.

I tried this

```
times = pd.read_excel(“timing.xlsx", 'Sheet1', index = False, delimiter='\t')


with open('example.tsv', 'wt') as out_file:
     tsv_writer = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter='\t')
     tsv_writer.writerow(['onset', 'duration', 'trial_type', 'block'])
     times.to_csv(out_file, index = False)
```

I also tried this

```
times = pd.read_excel(”timing.xlsx", 'Sheet1', index = False, delimiter='\t')

with open('example.tsv', 'wt') as out_file:
     tsv_writer = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter='\t')
     tsv_writer.writerow(['onset', 'duration', 'trial_type', 'block'])
     times.to_csv(out_file, mode = 'w', index = False, columns= ['onset', 'duration'])
```

This is what I got

```
onset   duration    trial_type  block
4.026,45.595            
68.026,45.595           
132.0336,45.593         
196.027,45.603          
260.027,45.603          
324.028,45.603
```

But I want this

```
onset   duration    trial_type  block
4.026    45.595         
68.026   45.595         
132.0336 45.593         
196.027  45.603         
260.027  45.603         
324.028  45.603
```

Comment: did you try different separator/delimiter in `to_csv()` ? See `sep` in documentation [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Comment: `to_csv` has also option to write headers so maybe you don't need `csv.writer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass sep=‘\t’ parameter in .to_csv

Comment: This works perfectly. I did sep = ',' before, and it doesn't work. I forgot I can use this way. Thank you so much.